# accented letters are not displayed correctly on the server, even if the encoding is correct

Tags: html, xhtml, utf-8, character-encoding

i wrote some html with utf-8 charset.
in the head of the html there is also a

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

everything works fine in local, but when i upload files to the server, i see all my letters

```
àèìòù etc
```

distorted.

anybody know how could it be the problem? is possible that the server force a charset that isn't utf-8?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the META tag is not all you need for correct UTF-8 encoding. Your server might still send the page as `Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1` in the header of the page.

You can check the headers e.g. with the [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/) Firefox add-on.

There is a lot of secret sauce with UTF-8 encoding and making it work, you might want to go through [this page (UTF-8: The Secret of Character Encoding)](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html) which explains everything you need to know and gives you advice on how to solve encoding problems.

To answer your question: Yes it is possible to force the server to use UTF-8, e.g. by using the PHP headers() function like so:

`header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');`

Comment: thanks a lot for the really interesting link!i was also trying this method AddDefaultCharset utf-8 in the .htacess but it wasn't working. yours works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 5):

Try saving the actual file with **utf-8 encoding**. That did the trick for me. 
I use PHPStorm as editor:  File->File Encoding->utf-8